# Connecting Thorlabs Powermeter via pymeasure

Tags: python

i'm currently trying to connect with my Thorlabs PM100USB Powermeter via pymeasure.
I'm using Win10 und pymeasure is installed via anaconda.

I found an old python script of my lab in an archive which connected to the powermeter via:

```
adapter = 'USB0::0x1313::0x8078::P0025186::INSTR'
power_meter = thorlabspm100usb.ThorlabsPM100USB(adapter)
```

But at this point I'm completly lost.
How do I get this address?
And yes, I have read the chapter on connecting to a device in the pymeasure documentation, but I can't figure it out either.

If I try to run the the code above the following error is raised:

> VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND (-1073807343): Insufficient location information or the requested device or resource is not present in the system.

May anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look [here](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/1.8/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thnaks, but the device is not listed in the ResourceManager. But it is listed in the Windows Device Manager.